# Doctor Who / Red Dwarf Crossovers?

Tags: doctor-who, red-dwarf

Are there any Doctor Who & Red Dwarf crossover media?  Or any mention of one in the other?

I know there's been a Who/Star Trek comic.  The Doctor has also namedropped meeting other sci-fi characters like Arthur Dent.

The crew of Red Dwarf are familiar with some 20th Century Media (Flintstones, Casablanca, Marilyn Monroe etc).

So, has Lister ever mentioned the TARDIS? Has the Doctor met Rimmer?  Does Cat know K9?  Is Kryten really a Cyberman?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zG_Cg6FwZrk

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aal-s7hpGAI

Comment: Ha! I was looking for something a *little* more cannon :-)

Comment: Well I haven't been faithful to dr who, but I have watched every red dwarf episode including the reboot (some of them a few times) there is no dr who cross-over happening on that side of the house.

Comment: Doesn't Red Dwarf have a 'no-aliens' rule?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this article on Ganymede](http://www.ganymede.tv/2007/02/now-you-see-it/) one of the special effects crew says

> There is a TARDIS model in the Blue Midget hanger from series 3 Red Dwarf– fact. (I know’ cos I put it there)

[image]
[image]
[image]

(Images via https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wVIb.jpg)

So, that's a (one-sided) cannon showing that someone took the TARDIS to JMC Red Dwarf :-)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if [this](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Dwarf_A-Z_(TV_story)) counts at all?

> Red Dwarf A-Z was a 1998 BBC TV special. Although principally spun off from the series Red Dwarf, one of its segments featured essentially a crossover between the Red Dwarf and Doctor Who universes as two Daleks were interviewed about the series under the letter "E", for "Exterminate". This was followed by a clip from the series which depicted a specific joke being discussed.
>
> As it is arguably parodical, the sketch is not considered a valid source on this Wiki. In addition, for the sake of common sense, our coverage of it is centered on the Dalek-focused sketch rather than the wider compilation, which is of minimal interest to scholars of the DWU.

Answer (score 3):

In a way, yes! In the Doctor Who Comic "Spam Filtered", the Doctor says he once knew a hard-light hologram who was a "bit of a jobsworth", in reference to Rimmer.

Comment: How do you know it was Rimmer?  There are a lot of people who could be described that way

Comment: @DavidW how many "hard-light hologram who was a 'bit of a jobsworth'"'s do you know?